# Are the SSH manual pages wrong?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

The ssh [manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201) pages states the following:

```
 -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
         forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side. 

 -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to
         be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.
```

Aren't those two descriptions mixed up?

When I use `ssh -L` it takes a remote port and "binds" (or forwards) it to a port on my local machine so that I can talk to some remote machine by talking to myself (localhost:port).

When I use `ssh -R` it takes a port from a computer on my local network and "binds" (or forwards) it to a port on the remote machine (ssh server). Then when I'm on the server, I can talk to the port of a computer on the same network as the computer that I just connected from using (localhost:port).

This also explains the use of L for local and R for remote (wherever the port is being bound to).

(I don't know if i'm using the word "bind" correctly. That't what I'm trying to imply with the quotes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have your definition of "forward" mixed up. It is the packets that are forwarded (from local to remote for `-L`, and from remote to local for `-R`).

Comment: Ah ok. So -L does bind to my local machine but packets are forwarded through that local port to the remote machine.

Comment: Exactly :-) Now you got it right!